# Noisy lines in LANDSAT-7 Dataset in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to perform Land Use/Land Cover(LULC) for my study area using LANDSAT-7 TIER 1 SURFACE REFLECTANCE, from year 2000. But as you can see below, it shows strange lines.

[image]

How can I perform LULC with this data? Will it be useful?

Here is the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2e1a3ec0471694df11ab4e82aa304582)

Comment: You can read about the Scan Line Correction fault on the [Landsat website](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-7?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#:~:text=Processing%20Details%C2%A0page.-,Landsat%207%20Scan%20Line%20Corrector%20(SLC)%20Failure,-Sources/Usage%3A%20Public)

Comment: @Matt, Thankyou for your reply. I read more about the Scan Line Correction fault, and found a solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-7?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#:%7E:text=Processing%20Details%C2%A0page.-,Landsat%207%20Scan%20Line%20Corrector%20(SLC)%20Failure,-Sources/Usage%3A%20Public) site shares the reasons in detail about this issue.

One such solution I found out was shared on [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_fill_the_Landsat_7_SLC-off_gap_data_using_google_earth_engine).

It makes use of focal_mean() function of GEE. You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-focalmean)

Below is the lines of code, that solved my issue.

```
var img_fill = l7.focal_mean(1, 'square', 'pixels', 8)

var final_image = img_fill.blend(l7)
```

Here is my code reference : https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a440d60dab819a72beec829c3c0a9b0